# Nr of monthly eggs that have converted to chickens based on nr of months

Tags: sequences-and-series, sumset

I get 1 egg per month every month, which convert to chickens in time t (e.g 9 or 15 months) from when I got the egg with probability P. Given a specific month, e.g 97, how many chickens do I have?

Comment: I don't think the question is clear. also try to include your thought and attempt.

Comment: You certainly cannot answer it without a more specific question.  Once you define it well enough, a spreadsheet can do it easily.